# Mimicking the action of `C-c C-n` in ess-R to work similarly in Python3

Tags: key-bindings

When one uses the ess ( emacs speaks statistics ) package written for R, `C-c c`, runs the whole buffer in the R interpreter in the other window. But, `C-c C-n` just runs one line which is sometimes convenient. There are also commands for doing other things like running a section of code where there are no blank lines ( one could think of it as a paragraph of R code ).

In Emacs with Python3, it seems that `C-c c` does the same thing as what happens in R as far as running the whole buffer. But is there something that I can add to my dotemacs file so that `C-c C-n` also works in Python3? Basically, I'd like to evaluate a line and get output in the Python interpreter rather than need to evaluate the whole buffer.

I did find something on the internet that might be an answer but I'm so Emacs Lisp illiterate that I couldn't even tell what the key binding was, given the Emacs Lisp code (I'm slowly going through the Emacs Lisp book by Robert Chassell which is quite readable with useful examples that I'm playing with). Maybe if I knew that, it would have worked. The code is [here](https://superuser.com/a/688834/697994) and the author says that it works, so it probably does.

Comment: BTW, the keybinding they set is `[S-return]` i.e "Shift RET". See e.g. https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Function-Keys.html

Comment: @NickD: Thanks. I'll try that and see how it goes.

Comment: Also, thanks for great edits.

Comment: @NickD: I still wasn't able to get that solution to work for me but  I found this link ( at bottom). It said that control enter evaluates a line in the buffer and I tried it and it worked for me !!!!!!!! It also says that shift control enter evaluates the whole buffer. That didn't work for me but control c c does so I can just use that for the whole buffer. Thanks for your generous efforts and edits. For people who know what they're doing in elisp, the link below has all sorts of goodies that you may find  helpful.  https://iqss.github.io/IQSS.emacs/init.html#run_python_in_emacs_(python-mode)